# Given a Group, how do I retrieve the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity of the Group (to set Security permissions)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

TL;DR: How do I get an Identity of a Team Group object?

In my understanding, security [Access Control Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20entries) use Identities to grant and revoke permissions to users and groups. In order to set a permission for something, I need to know that something's Identity. While browsing my ACEs, I found that [Team Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/groups) are given Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity references, with ACE records similar to:

```
{
  "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;X-X-X-XXXX...": {
    "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;X-X-X-XXXX...",
    "allow": 0
    "deny": 0
  }
}
```

These Identities can be queried from `https://{organization}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities` ... but I don't know how, given a Team Group (for example, `[MyTeamProject]\\Contributors`), how to retrieve that Team Group's unique Identity. [Team objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams) DO have a direct link to what I'm after with an `IdentityUrl` property, but I don't see anything that maps well for Groups. The Group object does have the `descriptor` property, but this doesn't work for urls like `https://{organization}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities?descriptors={descriptor}`.

What API call (or chain of calls) do I need to make in order to retrieve the security Identity of a Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo_Brendan,

I'm working through a POC of this right now and thought it might help you.  I'm using the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi to do this with the IdentityHttpClient.

I pulled the NuGet from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.131.1

ReadIdentitiesAsync and ReadIdentityAsync are the methods I'm using to get the Descriptor.  This simple code example allows you to add groups to a team in Azure DevOps.

The overloads of ReadIdentitiesAsync allow for more advanced searching & filtering so you could look for email addresses for individual users.  Hope this helps.

```
    public async Task AddGroupToTeam(WebApiTeam team, params string[] groups)
    {            
        var client = await GetConnectedClient<IdentityHttpClient>();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var result = await client.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.DisplayName, group);

            var teamIdentity = await client.ReadIdentityAsync(team.Id);
            var userIdentity = result.First();

            tasks.Add(client.AddMemberToGroupAsync(teamIdentity.Descriptor, userIdentity.Id));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }
```

ReadIdentitiesAsync appears to call this:

GET: https://spsprodeus23.vssps.visualstudio.com/{organization}/_apis/Identities?searchFilter=DisplayName&filterValue={groupName}&options=None&queryMembership=None

ReadIdentityAsync appears to call this:

GET: https://spsprodeus23.vssps.visualstudio.com/{organization}/_apis/Identities/{id}?queryMembership=None

Add to group

PUT: https://spsprodeus23.vssps.visualstudio.com/{organization}/_apis/identities/{Descriptor}/Members/{id}

Comment: Awesome, thank you! You got me on the right track, but I had to make a few tweaks... the final URL I used to find the Identity of a Group (given the DisplayName of the group, found using `https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/groups`) was `https://{organization}.vssps.visualstudio.com/_apis/Identities?searchFactor=DisplayName&factorValue={url-encoded-groupDisplayName}&options=None&queryMembership=None` (note the "filter" -> "factor" in queries)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't use the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.
IdentityHttpClient is only included in the old Client Api.